# How to scrape data from this website?

Tags: r, authentication, web-scraping

I need to login to this site http://bit.do for scraping purpose. Data are protected by password but I can't figure out how to log in the access them in R.

I tried

```
 library (rvest)

 url       <-"http://bit.d o/#login/admin"   
 pgsession <-html_session(url)               
 pgform    <-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]       


 filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
 'username' = "test0001", 
 'password' = "qwerty1234")

 submit_form(pgsession,filled_form)

 url <- 'http://bit.d o/admin/url/http%3A||2F||2Fedition.cnn.com||2F2017||2F07||2F21||2Fopinions||2Ftrump-russia-putin-lain-opinion||2Findex.html'
 data_page <- read_html(url)
 data_link<- html_nodes(data_page,'td > a')
 data_click<- html_nodes(data_page,'td span:nth-child(1)')
```

but I get this kind of error

```
 Submitting with 'NULL'
 Error in xml2::url_absolute(form$url, session$url) : 
 Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL].
```

How could I do? These are my testing credential username: test0001, password: qwerty1234. Here's an example of protected data I want to scrape http://bit.d o/admin/url/http%3A||2F||2Fedition.cnn.com||2F2017||2F07||2F21||2Fopinions||2Ftrump-russia-putin-lain-opinion||2Findex.html

IMPORTANT: NOTE THAT DUE TO A StackOverflow RESTRICTION I PUT A SPACE BETWEEN the d and o in domain name

Answer (score 1):

Since the form has no `url` field, when you call `submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)` a call to `xml2::url_absolute(form$url, session$url)` takes place that doesn't work because `form$url` is `NULL`. In order to get past this, you need to give a value – even if it is empty – to the `form$url` that is called by `url_absolute`. Try adding the following line after you populate the `filled_form` with `set_values`:

```
filled_form$url <- ''
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Oriol. I tried  

     `filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
     'username' = "test0001", 
     'password' = "qwerty1234")
     filled_form$url <- ' '
     submit_form(pgsession,filled_form)`

and I got 

`<session> http://bit.do/?username=test0001&password=qwerty1234&NULL=Login
  Status: 200
  Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Size:   34650`

Unfortunately it doesn't worked  :(

Comment: Hmmm... I'm confused. You get a login status of 200. Doesn't that mean that you logged in successfully? What is the problem?

Comment: Despite of status of 200 login was unsuccesful and scraping returns no data. You can see it by yourself, I wrote my testing credentials above

Comment: Right. I was only trying to get you past the error message. If you look at the code for the form, you'll see this: `onSubmit="chklogin(); return(false);"`. This means that the form is never sent normally (that's what the `return(false)` does. Instead, it calls the javascript function `chklogin()`. As far as I know, you can't trigger it from `rvest`, so you would need to use a Selenium Server and RSelenium. If you're willing to do this and can wait for a couple of days, I'm happy to post a more detailed answer. Or you can ask a different question specifically for this. Let me know.

Comment: Surely I can wait, I've been trying to fix this since more than a week with bad results (so frustrating!!!). Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: @MassimoPotenzi Did you get any update on this? I'm also having the same issue,